# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column submittedby_id is not unique

Tags: django, model-view-controller

I am having a hard time getting around this error.
This is how my model looks like right now.

```
class trendingideas(models.Model):
        submit = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        iname = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique = True)
        idea = models.TextField(unique = True)
        support = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
        submittedon = models.DateTimeField()
        readbyadmin = models.BooleanField()
        feasibilitycheck = models.BooleanField()

        def __str_(self):
                return str(self.iname)

class trendingidea_admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('submit','iname','idea','support','submittedon','readbyadmin','feasibilitycheck')
```

**submit defined above was before defined as: 
submittedby = models.ForeignKey(User)**

I made some changes and now no matter what i do, I keep getting the error:

```
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column submittedby_id is not unique.
```

**if I do inspectdb i see the poblematic column(stale entry)**

```
class HomeTrendingidea(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    iname = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=15)
    idea = models.TextField(unique=True)
    submittedon = models.DateField()
    support = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    readbyadmin = models.BooleanField()
    feasibilitycheck = models.BooleanField()
    submittedby = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    assignedto = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'home_trendingidea'
```

How can i get it working back?
thank you in advance.

Comment: have you done `makemigrations` and `migrate` ??

Comment: makemigrations says no changes detected and migrate is the one that is giving me .IntegrityError.

Comment: never mind. it was a lab server.
i did showmigrations
saw the point where it was not checked around 12 files.
landed up deleting migrations files. Now it does not give me that error.
not sure what was wrong.